# ST_ConcaveHull recomposes polygon without much regard to concavity?

Tags: postgis, concave-hull

What am I missing in understanding this behavior of concave hull?

My primitive understanding is that it applies a "shrink wrap" algorithm. But consider this example where I decompose a polygon into points which I then try to use to demonstrate how concave hull works:

```
SELECT ST_ConcaveHull( ST_Collect((dp).geom),.1) As poly, ST_Collect((dp).geom) as pts
FROM (SELECT ST_DumpPoints(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-122.475085089839 37.7198717176919,-122.470177269155 37.7120226246913,-122.471830990254 37.7074225016154,
                               -122.48287358496 37.7032441601418,-122.475191779947 37.7118960196031,-122.483033622565 37.7178040272001,
                               -122.479246067554 37.7246820410903,-122.465429486076 37.7274668223806,-122.464469260449 37.7204202784789,
                               -122.464522607945 37.7132886636764,-122.466709786911 37.7067472287748,-122.473538058848 37.6988123284593,
                               -122.483140315115 37.6981369771754,-122.493222684195 37.7075491143465,-122.483673772983 37.726411993946,
                               -122.468790275769 37.7339642375358,-122.500317683845 37.7196185341229,-122.461962006274 37.7007117173384,
                               -122.475085089839 37.7198717176919))',4326)) AS dp
   ) As foo;
```

Here's what it produces vs what I expected:

[image]

From comments below, I realized the best I can do is with factor of 0.99

[image]

Comment: Perhaps try with projected coordinate system.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant but I wrapped points with `ST_Transform((dp).geom,4326))` which made no difference.

Comment: Shrink factor of 0.1 seems to be too big for those points and algorithm makes weird result. 0.9 yields a better polygon.

Comment: as @user30184 implied, the factor has an almost logarithmic impact on the result. try slowly decreasing from 0.99 to 0.9; in that range the result is most likely close to what one might expect.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem. 0.99 produces a much more reasonable result.  I updated question. Not sure how to close my question! Any recommendations?

Comment: @ThingumaBob your comment looks like it would be worth providing as an answer.